# Vertical Table in Material-UI

Tags: html-table, material-ui

By vertical table, I mean the first column of each row is a header. Like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, to render the `<TableCell />` to be a `<th />` we need to wrap it inside `<TableHead />`, otherwise it will render to `<td />`. But `<TableHead />` also cannot be placed inside `<TableRow />` since it renders to `<thead />`. So the following code won't work:

```html
<Table>
    <TableRow>
        <TableHead>
            <TableCell>Header 1</TableCell>
        </TableHead>
        <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TableHead>
            <TableCell>Header 1</TableCell>
        </TableHead>
        <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Then, how can I achieve the first example using Material-UI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ohh, Nevermind.

I am not keen enough to see the `variant` property in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/). All you need to do is set the `variant` property of `<TableCell />` to `head`.

```js
<Table>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell variant="head">Header 1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell variant="head">Header 1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 9):

The approved solution will generate the following error message :

```
<tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>. Add a <tbody>, <thead> or <tfoot> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser
```

So you may want to add a `<tbody>` tag as below :

```
<Table>
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell variant="head">Header 1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Cell 1</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell variant="head">Header 1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Cell 2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Otherwise you do get that error.